# Difference between Select @@version and "About version"

Tags: sql-server, ssms

```
SELECT @@version
```

outputs:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5343.0 (X64)
```

while

```
HELP > About
```

is showing

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
```

When I try to execute the command `Select EOMONTH(SYSDATE())`, it has no errors, returning me the expected result but at text editor the function has a red line indicating error as `eomonth is not a recognized built-in function name`.

As stated in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/hh213020.aspx),`EOMONTH()` is supported only in 2012 and above which in other word  `Select @@version` is the version of the db execution engine version while "Help > About" is the SSMS version?

Comment: We have SQL Server 2014 and using SSMS 2016, try to update SSMS to 2012 or 2014 version.

Comment: The fact that running `@@version` will return you the server version is rather logical, since it's a query you are executing against the server, where `Help > About` can only return you the version of the SSMS you are using. It's perfectly possible to connect to several servers at once in SSMS, so having it return a version of those servers wouldn't make a lot of sense. SSMS and a MSSQL Server aren't tied together in a 1 on 1 relationship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SELECT @@Version` shows you the version of the **database engine**, while `Help > About` most likely shows the version of the **management tool** (assuming you're talking about the `Help > About` option in SSMS).

Those don't need to be the same, but as for features, it's usually more important what version the **engine** is.... so in your case - the engine seems to properly execute the `EOMONTH()` function (which proves it's at least SQL Server **2012** - or newer), while the SSMS GUI tool doesn't know about that function yet (and thus highlights it as a potential error)

Comment: We all have this confusion we start using SSMS